# R: How to cache scraped websites (XML package) for later processing

Tags: html, xml, r, caching

I have the following function to webscrape websites:

```
library(XML)

dl_url <- function(link_url) {
con <- url(link_url)
raw_data <- readLines(con)
close(con)
parsed_data <- htmlTreeParse(raw_data, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
parsed_data
}
```

When I use:

```
URLs <- lapply(list_urls, dl_url)
```

I get the expected list of parsed websites,

```
str(URLs):

List of x
 $ :Classes 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument' <externalptr> 
 $ :Classes 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument' <externalptr>
....
```

However, I am unable to store the data. dput(URLs) only yields a 1 kb file with text in it.

What is the best way to locally cache (parsed) html websites in R?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use `useInternalNodes=F` if you want to be able to save the object.

Comment: I usually download the raw HTML and save that locally (if caching/saving is needed) before parsing.

Comment: I usually use `save` to save R objects. Not sure if it will work in your case.

Comment: Can you give an example of a website that you are trying to webscrap?